# XHR failed loading: GET <api> Angular 2

Tags: mongodb, angular, google-chrome, backend, developer-tools

Why are there a lot of error like this in my Developer Tool. I am working with frontend, internet connection is fine. What does this error mean?

`XHR failed loading: GET "http://192.168.0.111:3000/api/clients"`

That is just one example but I get a lot of that in console (Chrome)

Comment: I back end service running? Do you have `http` module in you `package.json dependencies`?

Comment: Yes. Data is reflected in frontend but it has that error in console. @mxr7350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to fetch some resources from different server(cross-origin). If it happens locally make sure that all files are in correct places and you have local http server up and running.

Comment: I'm sure it isn't cross-origin. What could be other possibilities that this is happening? The error appeared after adding id to data.